# JSON not picking up <br>

Tags: json, html, html-entities

I have a webpage which uses JSON files for content, but for some reason, not all JSON elements are picking up the html entity `<br>`and I cannot figure out why...

```
"pages": [{
    "title": "Title",
    "intro": "Lorum<br>Ipsm",
    "content": [
       {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "text": [
            {"content": "Lorum<br>Ipsm"}
                    ]
       },...
```

The `<br>` in my `"content"` is shown as a line break, but in my `"intro"`it's not... What can be the cause of this strange behavior?

I call the JSON by using this HTML:

```
<article class="a_page">
    <section class="left">
        <header>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </header>

        <section>
            <p>{{intro}}</p>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section class="right">
        {{#content}}
        <section>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                <section>
                    {{#text}}
                        <section>
                    <!--<h3>{{title}}</h3>-->
                    <p>{{{content}}}</p>
                </section>
                {{/text}}
            </section>
        </section>
        {{/content}}
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: What template engine do you use?

Comment: .. which uses Mustache.js internally; documentation says text with tags should be enclosed in triple curly braces. Use {{{intro}}} instead of {{intro}}

Comment: Hi Tommi, great!! Please add this as a answer, so I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mustache.js documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) says you should enclose text with tags in triple curly braces.
use

```
{{{intro}}}
```

instead of

```
{{intro}}
```